# C# String.Replace() & Regex.Replace() not working at my end

Tags: c#

I am trying to replace a string with some other string but nothing is working. i tried **Regex.Replace() & String.Replace()** but no luck.

See this code example

```
string maindata = "Operational Metrics~Domestic Subscribers Disney+~2015 FY~9999";
string data = "Operational Metrics~Domestic Subscribers Disney+~2015 FY~9999";

                 //data = Regex.Escape(data);
        
                 string strformula = Regex.Replace(maindata, "\"" + data.Replace("(", "\\(").Replace(")", "\\)").Replace("$", "\\$") + "\"", "W51",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                 strformula = maindata.Replace("\"" + data.Replace("(", "\\(").Replace(")", "\\)").Replace("$", "\\$") + "\"", "W51");
```

**Regex.Escape(data); also does not work.**

I really do not understand the reason behind why this replace is getting fail ? please guide me what is lacking there ?

Thanks

### EDIT

```
string maindata = "Operational Metrics~Domestic Subscribers Disney+~2015 FY~9999";
string data =     "Operational Metrics~Domestic Subscribers Disney+~2015 FY~9999";
string strformula = Regex.Replace(maindata, data , "W51",RegexOptions.None);
```

I simplify the code now see **Regex.Replace** not working.

Comment: this looks like a contender for an obfuscated code competition. could you add an example of expected output, so we could take it from there?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "does not work"? Are you getting an error? The wrong result?

Comment: It doesn't seem like the characters you want you replace are present in you data strings

Comment: i want to replace `Operational Metrics~Domestic Subscribers Disney+~2015 FY~9999` with `W51`. if you run my code then definitely understand that Replace is getting fail to replace.

Comment: your code doesn't make sense. especially the part where you overwrite `strformula` in the line after you assign it.

Comment: Why are you using `Regex.Replace`? Why not [`String.Replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace)?

Comment: why people gave me so many negative marks where i posted here what i tried.

Comment: Do not worry about negative marks. you will eventually get some positive points for some good questions. You can check this article on how to ask a  good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: The remarks are not meant to be "negative", but they are critical. We are just openly venting our thought process. We are trying to understand your code, because if we don't understand it, we cannot help you. And this seemed effective, as it motivated you to make an edit that has code that we can understand. (We call that a [mcve]).

Answer (score 1):

Change `data` from:

```
string data = "Operational Metrics~Domestic Subscribers Disney+~2015 FY~9999";
```

to

```
string data = @"Operational Metrics~Domestic Subscribers Disney\+~2015 FY~9999";
```

You have to escape the `+` character with a backslash because `+` has a [special meaning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/quantifiers-in-regular-expressions#match-one-or-more-times-) in regex.

Also I have used a verbatim string here(note the `@` prefix). In verbatim strings `\` doesn't have a special meaning, so characters like `\n` will be printed as it is instead of a new line. If you do not want yo use verbatim strings, you will need to use two backslashes:

```
string data = "Operational Metrics~Domestic Subscribers Disney\\+~2015 FY~9999";
```

Comment: i did escape now but still not working. here is sample code. `            string maindata = @"Operational Metrics~Domestic Subscribers Disney+~2015 FY~9999";
            string data =     @"Operational Metrics~Domestic Subscribers Disney+~2015 FY~9999";

            maindata = Regex.Escape(maindata);
            data = Regex.Escape(data);

            string strformula = Regex.Replace(maindata, data , "W51",RegexOptions.None);`

Comment: @BabuBhatt Don't use `Regex.Escape()` on `maindata`. Use it only on `data`.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use regex

```
string maindata = "Operational Metrics~Domestic Subscribers Disney+~2015 FY~9999";
string data =     "Operational Metrics~Domestic Subscribers Disney+~2015 FY~9999";
string strformula = maindata.Replace(data , "W51");
```

already replaces the line for W51.
[on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gZkxDm)

Comment: This should be marked as the accepted answer. I was carried away with the use of Regex in the OP.